# Blazor WASM issue with Identity Server 5 can not get .well-known/openid-configuration

Tags: .net, .net-core, blazor-webassembly

i have started learning Blazor WASM and deployed a small project via Dockerfile with Identity Server 5 with dotnet 6. i am getting following error screenshot link is

https://ibb.co/XyytVJW

```
AuthenticationService.js:2 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://oncall.hardstoneenterprises.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://oncall.hardstoneenterprises.com/.well-known/openid-configuration'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I understand that a call should be send on HTTPS but it is actually sent on HTTP. But why Blazor WASM is sending on HTTP when my website is running on HTTPS which is exactly browser is logging. I am using default setup that comes with dotnet template.

```
dotnet new blazorwasm --pwa --auth Individual --hosted -o OnCallTrackerWASM
```

Server side program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// builder.WebHost.UseWebRoot("wwwroot").UseStaticWebAssets(); // The fix.
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
// Serilog configuration        
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .CreateLogger();
// Register Serilog
builder.Logging.AddSerilog(logger);
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddApplication();
builder.Services.AddInfrastructure(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAppUrlProvider, AppUrlProvider>();
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
builder.Services.AddScoped<INotificationHubService, NotificationHubService>();
builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();;

builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add(CustomClaimsTypes.DepartmentId);
        options.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add(CustomClaimsTypes.DepartmentId);
        
        options.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add(CustomClaimsTypes.HospitalId);
        options.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add(CustomClaimsTypes.HospitalId);
        
        options.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add(CustomClaimsTypes.Role);
        options.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add(CustomClaimsTypes.Role);
        
        
    })
    // .AddProfileService<MyProfileService>()
    ;
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Remove("role");
builder.Services.AddTransient<IProfileService, MyProfileService>();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerJwt();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
var mvcBuilder = builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Admin", "AdminPolicy");
});
    
if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    mvcBuilder.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
}
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(x =>
{
    x.AddPolicy("AdminPolicy", policy =>
        policy.RequireClaim(CustomClaimsTypes.ManageHospitalUsers));
    
    x.AddPolicy(PolicyNames.ApiSecure, policy =>
        policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(IdentityServerJwtConstants.IdentityServerJwtScheme)
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser());
});
builder.Services.AddSignalR();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, SubBasedUserIdProvider>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IFileBaseMessagingService, FileBaseMessagingService>();
builder.Services.AddResponseCompression(opts =>
{
    opts.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(
        new[] { "application/octet-stream" });
});

FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
{
    Credential = GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault(),
});

//building app server
var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseResponseCompression();
}
//initial migration
using (var service = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var dbContext = service.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
    var userManager = service.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
    var roleManager = service.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
    //To create default folders
    var _ = service.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IFileManager>();
    await dbContext.Database.MigrateAsync();

    if (!dbContext.Roles.Any())
    {
        var allRoles = Enum.GetValues<Role>()
            .ToList();
        foreach (var role in allRoles)
        {
            await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole
            {
                Id = role.ToString(),
                Name = role.GetAttribute<DisplayAttribute>().Name,
            });
        }
    }

    if (!dbContext.RoleClaims.Any())
    {
        dbContext.RoleClaims.Add(new IdentityRoleClaim<string>
        {
            RoleId = Role.Root.ToString(),
            ClaimType = CustomClaimsTypes.ManageHospitalUsers,
            ClaimValue = "*"
        });
        dbContext.RoleClaims.Add(new IdentityRoleClaim<string>
        {
            RoleId = Role.Root.ToString(),
            ClaimType = CustomClaimsTypes.CreateHospitalAdmin,
            ClaimValue = "*"
        });
        dbContext.RoleClaims.Add(new IdentityRoleClaim<string>
        {
            RoleId = Role.Root.ToString(),
            ClaimType = CustomClaimsTypes.ManageDepartments,
            ClaimValue = "*"
        });
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    
    if (!dbContext.Hospitals.Any())
    {
        var hospital = new Hospital
        {
            Id = GuidExtension.NewSeq,
            Name = "Root Hosital",
            Address = "Can not reach",
            IsVirtual = true,
            CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow
        };
        var department = new Department
        {
            Id = GuidExtension.NewSeq,
            DisplayName = "Medicine"
        };
        hospital.Departments.Add(department);
        hospital.Departments.Add(new Department
        {
            Id = GuidExtension.NewSeq,
            DisplayName = "Surgery"
        });

        var rootAdmin = new ApplicationUser
        {
            Id = GuidExtension.NewSeq,
            UserName = "root",
            Email = "root@localhost",
            EmailConfirmed = true,
            Name = "root",
            Department = department,
            Hospital = hospital,
        };
        rootAdmin.UserRoles.Add(new IdentityUserRole<string>
        {
            UserId = rootAdmin.Id,
            RoleId = Role.Root.ToString()
        });
        await userManager.CreateAsync(rootAdmin, "Admin@123");
        // dbContext.Hospitals.Add(hospital);
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        await SeedData.DevelopmentData(app.Services);
    }
}
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();


app.MapRazorPages();
app.UseMiddleware<ApiExceptionMiddleware>();
app.MapControllers();
app.AddGenerateCallRoutes();
app.AddViewCallRoutes();
app.AddCallActionRoutes();
app.AddAuthRoutes();
app.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/api/notification-hub");
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

My client side program.cs file

```
var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);

builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");
builder.Services.AddSingleton<SignalRConnectionManager>();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("OnCallTracker.ServerAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

// Supply HttpClient instances that include access tokens when making requests to the server project
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("OnCallTracker.ServerAPI"));

builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddBlazoredToast();

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

My docker file is auto generated via rider

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Server/OnCallTracker.Server.csproj", "Server/"]
COPY ["Domain/Domain.csproj", "Domain/"]
COPY ["Shared/OnCallTracker.Shared.csproj", "Shared/"]
COPY ["Application/Application.csproj", "Application/"]
COPY ["Client/OnCallTracker.Client.csproj", "Client/"]
COPY ["Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj", "Infrastructure/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Server/OnCallTracker.Server.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Server"
RUN dotnet build "OnCallTracker.Server.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "OnCallTracker.Server.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "OnCallTracker.Server.dll"]
```

Edited:1
One finding i made that i missed in docs

```
OidcConfigurationController (Controllers/OidcConfigurationController.cs
```

Blazor WASM call this end point to oidc related configuration. I tried hardcoding schema to https

```
[HttpGet("_configuration/{clientId}")]
    public IActionResult GetClientRequestParameters([FromRoute]string clientId)
    {
        HttpContext.Request.Scheme = "https";
        var parameters = ClientRequestParametersProvider.GetClientParameters(HttpContext, clientId);
        return Ok(parameters);
    }
```

Now in session storage store right configuration with HTTPS, but still i am getting error

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://oncall.hardstoneenterprises.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure frame 'http://oncall.hardstoneenterprises.com/connect/authorize?client_id=OnCallTracker.Client&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Foncall.hardstoneenterprises.com%2Fauthentication%2Flogin-callback&response_type=code&scope=OnCallTracker.ServerAPI%20openid%20profile&state=d169678dc8594343ae383a7d49440b0c&code_challenge=95twa7cs1ILe8DpaGBmhvoL3ZvxdZnRbAvYhWpl-z4g&code_challenge_method=S256&prompt=none&response_mode=query'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS. from file AuthenticationService.js
```

Comment: I found that browser is caching invalid url, means it should be with HTTPS with is with HTTP https://ibb.co/j3JnWhj

Comment: Issue is still pending. I have moved back to Angular. i wanted to try blazor in one of my small projects but judging by the current situation, i guess i will have to wait. My overral experience was ok but Blazor WASM still very small community to help. Angular, React, Vue on the other hand are still better for large projects.

Comment: I'm having this same issue and can't find any info on it. Mine is deployed to an Ubuntu server running nginx.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue on Ubuntu server with nginx. After days of searching and trying different things I finally found what I needed to do to fix this issue. I needed to add this:

```
builder.Services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(
    IdentityServerJwtConstants.IdentityServerJwtBearerScheme, 
    options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "{AUTHORITY}";
    });
```

right after this:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddIdentityServerJwt();
```

like mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-5.0#azure-app-service-on-linux-1

and here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/25430#issuecomment-760911529